# What is the Linux 3.16 equivalent of SPIN_LOCK_UNLOCKED?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, kernel-module

Here is a line from a kernel module that I wrote for a 2.x kernel.

```
static spinlock_t mr_lock = SPIN_LOCK_UNLOCKED;
```

When I try to compile this module for a 3.16 kernel, I get the following build error.

```
error: ‘SPIN_LOCK_UNLOCKED’ undeclared here (not in a function)
```

When I look at the 3.16 version of [`linux/spinlock_types.h`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/spinlock_types.h?v=3.16#L76), which defines the `spinlock_t` type for this kernel, there is indeed no SPIN_LOCK_UNLOCKED constant anymore.

However, it is not clear how to initialize a spinlock to unlocked for this kernel.

What is the correct way to achieve the same initialization?

Comment: The kernel has changed its internal API a number of times. Look the current documentation for what you want to achieve.

Comment: @merlin2011 Total guess here ,, maybe `spin_lock_init()`? This also says `SPIN_LOCK_UNLOCKED` is valid so it must be on the old side: http://www.linuxgrill.com/anonymous/fire/netfilter/kernel-hacking-HOWTO-5.html

Comment: @LtWorf, Forgive my ignorance, but could you link me to the relevant documentation about correct usage of kernel SpinLocks? I have found general documentation [here](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/Documentation/kbuild/modules.txt?v=3.16) and [here](https://www.kernel.org/doc/), but I'm not sure how to identify what I seek.

Answer (score 5):

It depends on how you were using it.

```
#define DEFINE_SPINLOCK(x)    spinlock_t x = __SPIN_LOCK_UNLOCKED(x)

to replace code like:

  spinlock_t init_lock = SPIN_LOCK_UNLOCKED;

with the improved:

  DEFINE_SPINLOCK(init_lock);
```

I took the above from this

https://www.mail-archive.com/kernelnewbies@nl.linux.org/msg02836.html

Comment: Or since the original variable is declared `static`, use `static DEFINE_SPINLOCK(init_lock);`.